How to trigger a wallet connect from onClick with solana-web3.js or @solana/wallet-adapter-react
I have code like this:

const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet()

... some code, then this:

          try {
            if (!publicKey) {


And in that if (!publicKey) { I want to trigger wallet connect.

The thing above. How can I do it?
